# what part of memory are array allocated in c

Tags: c, arrays, memory, microcontroller

In c, when you declare an array like `int buffans[46];`, what part of memory is this created in?

The reason I'm asking is because my mcu appears to hanging when I get to this part of the code, but when I use a smaller array `int buffans[26];` it works ok.

I'm wondering if I am running out of memory?

```
void getRes(int length){
  int i;
  int buff[46];
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    buff[i] = getch(UART_7)); 
  }
  buff[i] = 0;
  TI_PRINTF("\nANS ");
  for( i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    TI_PRINTF("[%x]", buff[i]);
  }
  TI_PRINTF("\n");
}
```

Comment: Show the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: It depends _where_  it is declared.

Comment: It depends on where and how the array is declared.  We need to see the code.  If you're working on a system made any time after 1980, the the space taken up by 26 `int`s is negligible.

Comment: @JohnBode, Thanks I've included the code.

Comment: Here `bufans` is located on the stack because it's a local variable. So it looks as if you run out of stack space. On the other hand changing from 26 to 46 `ints` is just 40/80 more bytes depending on the size of `int` and that is still not very much.

Comment: The C standard does not specify memory allocation details.

Comment: I've posted the memory specs for the mcu. Which spec does the stack come under?

Comment: @MichaelWalz: This is a microcontroller. For some of them, there is not data-stack (e.g. PIC). Even iff, there are some other memory allocatrion strategies for local variables.

Comment: @MichaelWalz it is if you've only allowed 40 words of stack for your thread.

Comment: @transcend and which is your micro controller ?

Comment: Are you running an RTOS tasker?

Comment: @Olaf if it's a PIC, may as well commit suicide:(

Comment: @MartinJames: No! The PIC is a _great_ MCU. Many peripherals, high speed, good CPU core. Ehm ... you **are** talking about PIC32, are you? ;-)

Comment: I assume length never exceeds 25?

Comment: thanks for the code but if you want to know if you are running out of memory we need to know how much you have.  basically what platform is this, chip, board, whatever you know.  what toolchain are you using (so that you can dump your binary in some way once we have an understanding of the target).  It is quite possible you are running out of memory but it could be other things as well.  could be completely unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

In the posted code, the array is created on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

It's allocated in the "stack", but the programming doc of your MCU should describe what the "stack" actually is for your code.

If it's indeed a lack of memory issue (because of 8KB for stack + heap to share with every process/thread running), note that you don't need an array in your function:

```
void getResponse(int length){
  int i;

  TI_PRINTF("\nANS ");
  for( i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    TI_PRINTF("[%x]", getch(UART_) );
  }
  TI_PRINTF("\n");
}
```

Comment: @transcend you're welcome. You only have 8KB for everything (all allocated memory, stack + heap), so every byte counts...

Comment: @llya, you referring to the 8kB SRAM here? This is where the stack and heap are stored?

Comment: @transcend yes, and you probably have less available for your process or thread. It should be specified in the programming docs.

Comment: despite the obvious optimization, still important to understand why what seems like not a lot of ram is causing problems for the poster.  they will just hit this again at some point.

Comment: @dwelch well, if you scale to desktop-PC RAM sizes, 40 bytes is like allocating a 40MB array. So proportionaly, that's a lot. I bet you're thinking twice before trying to allocate 40 MB on the stack, aren't you ?

Comment: 46 ints is 184 bytes, which for a pic is a ton, for an arm based, is less painful from a small number of percent to a fraction of a percent, but either way, if the user cant allocate 184 bytes on the stack they need to know why because they will hit it again.   I am very well versed in bare metal mcus, I know the difference between a pc and a microcontroller.

Comment: teach them to fish rather than give them a fish.  your solution is good, but you have given them the fish not solved the real problem of what happened.

Comment: @dwelch you're right, but i'm also giving him the address of the fishing accessories store. Unfortunately the store is closed (i.e. the Intel D2000 programming manual is behind a wall).